# preg_match() different on php CLI vs mod_php

Tags: php, apache, pcre

Good folks. I have a basic regex match in a `script.php` file.

```
<?php
  $str = "ABC";
  echo ( preg_match( "|AB(C)|", $str) ) . PHP_EOL; 
?>
```

When I execute the code from the command line, as expected the output is 1.

```
php script.php 
1
```

Now calling `preg_match()` with exactly the same arguments, using Apache Http as the PHP runtime environment:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$str = "ABC";
   if ( preg_match( "|AB(C)|", $str) ) {
     $res = 'matches';
   } else {
     $res = 'no match';
   }
   echo $res;
?>
</body>
<html>
```

The result is `no match`.

How is this possible? Apparently `ldd` and `httpd` are linked to the same libpcre version.

```
ldd /usr/local/bin/php | grep libpcre
libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007faa7e217000)
ldd /usr/sbin/httpd | grep libpcre
libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007fd9e3c75000)
```

`php -i` and `phpinfo()` return the same version of the PCRE library and config.

```
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.38 2015-11-23
PCRE JIT Support => enabled
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.jit => 1 => 1
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000
```

`find / -name libpcre.*` returns multiple results:

```
/usr/lib64/pkconfig/libpcre.pc
/usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.9
/usr/lib64/libpcre.so
/usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1
```

`/usr/lib64/pkconfig/libpcre.pc` points to PCRE version 8.41, which is also returned by `pcre-config --version`. This is probably the system version.

`/usr/lib64/libpcre.so` and `/usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1` are symbolic links to 
`/usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.9`.

I'm running `Apache/2.4.27` and `PHP/7.1.11` 
OS version is `Fedora 24`.

Comment: It works ok on the [php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1685e650f94c48a7c51a31690f935f0ae9a7022f)

Comment: Setting `pcre.jit=0` fixed the problem.